reCAPTCHA Enterprise not working in ios project
I'm facing an issue running the project after install pod "RecaptchaEnterprise", "18.5.0".
Please ses the screenshot and guide me how i can resolved this issue.



Try to update xCode to 15.3.
Found soluton here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/recaptcha-enterprise-mobile-sdk/issues/109.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
